# Update Data Extension from text response

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, mobileconnect

I've been working on an alternative solution to using non-keyword responses. I've been able to get that part working, however, when I try adding an AMPscript function to add or update a data extension record, I get an error thrown at me saying "There was an error processing your message".

Here's what I have set up:

Outbound message:
**"Hi! Would you like to receive more mobile messages? Reply Y or N**

```
%%[
var @nxtkywrd 
set @nxtkywrd = CreateSmsConversation("85240",MOBILE_NUMBER,"Next_Keyword","MOBILECONNECT")
]%%
```

**Text Response message:**

```
%%[ VAR @message
IF (Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)]) == "YES") OR (Uppercase([MSG(0).NOUN(0)]) == "Y") THEN
SET @message = "Thank you for consenting to receive messages."
ELSE
SET @message = "Ok, no more messages"
ENDIF ]%%
%%=v(@message)=%%

%%[ VAR @response
SET @response = v([MSG(0).NOUNS])
UpsertData('Data_Extension',1,'Mobile_Phone',MobileNumber,'Text_1_Response',@response)
]%%
```

The text response works without the UpsertData function. I've tried InsertData, UpdateData, but none seem to work. Any suggestions?

Thanks!
Sean

Comment: Cameron, thanks for the suggestion, however, I'm still getting the same error with your approach. I did remove @response from the code since it wasn't getting used but I'm still at a loss for why it's not working.

What I'd like to do is store and submit what a user would reply with, whether that's a one word/letter or a short phrase response in a data extension.

Comment: would you be able to share details on "I've been working on an alternative solution to using non-keyword responses. I've been able to get that part working"? We're trying to do this too for a private shortcode and I'd like to ask you some questions about it. Thanks! Kevin

Comment: Is this resolved ? I came across the same issue and you need to do something like this `SET @response2 = UpsertData('Data_Extension',1,'Mobile_Phone',MobileNumber,'Text_1_Response',@response)`

Answer (score 1):

You were very close Sean! I was able to get your code working as follows:

```
%%[
VAR @msg,@response,@inbound
SET @inbound = [MSG(0).NOUN(0)]
IF Uppercase(@inbound) == "YES" OR Uppercase(@inbound) == "Y" THEN
    SET @msg = "Thank you for consenting to receive messages."
    UpsertData('Data_Extension',1,'Mobile_Phone',Mobile_Number,'Text_1_Response',"YES")
ELSE
    SET @msg = "Ok, no more messages"
    UpsertData('Data_Extension',1,'Mobile_Phone',Mobile_Number,'Text_1_Response',"NO")
ENDIF
]%%
%%=v(@msg)=%%
```

**Changes**:

- AMPScript code for the Mobile Number of the customer is
  "**Mobile_Number**"
- You don't need **v()** inside an AMPScript
  Block to capture values.
- Changed the UpsertData function to explicit YES and NO, as it looked like you were capturing subscription flags.

Hopefully this gets you closer to achieving your goal!

Comment: It doesn't work for me. My Text Response message only has this %%[
UpsertData('InnovationDE',1,'phone',Mobile_Number,'last',"Yo Yo") 
]%%

Comment: Hi @Maneesh, double check the 'phone' reference in your call - this may need to be 'Mobile_Phone' as in my example above. Also assuming the DE has the field 'last' as a [text] type?